# Pandas subtracting rows gives wrong result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe consists of a Column "timeStamp", the elements of which are of type datetime.datetime. I'm trying to obtain the difference between two consecutive rows of this column to obtain the time spent in seconds. I use the following piece of code for it.

```
df["Time"] = df["timeStamp"].diff(0).dt.total_seconds()
```

Generally it's working fine, however, I keep getting 0.0 as a result of this operation in quite a few instances even when it's not the case.

Examples values that result in 0.0:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'S.No.': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ABC': [datetime.datetime(2019,2,25,11,49,50), datetime.datetime(2019,2,25,11,50,0),datetime.datetime(2019,2,25,11,50,7),datetime.datetime(2019,2,25,11,50,12)]})

df["Time"] = df["ABC"].diff(0).dt.seconds

print df
```

Note: using python2.7

Comment: the problem was the "diff(0)", it should be diff()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(df["timestamp"].diff().fillna(0).dt.seconds)

0     0
1    10
2     7
3     5

df['difference']=df["timestamp"].diff().fillna(0).dt.seconds
print(df)

            timestamp  difference
0 2019-02-25 11:49:50           0
1 2019-02-25 11:50:00          10
2 2019-02-25 11:50:07           7
3 2019-02-25 11:50:12           5
```

Comment: Now I'm getting 0 instead of 0.0

Comment: how about using `df["timestamp"]=df["timestamp"].apply(np.datetime64)` and then check  if dtype is converted to `datetime64[ns]` then this code should work.

Comment: I've added some code to my question now, does it run correctly for you?

Comment: `df["ABC"].diff().fillna(0).dt.seconds` still works for me, the link you have added in the comments is inaccessible for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
df["Time"] = df["timeStamp"].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

instead.

The argument in [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) specifies the number of rows above of the row with which you want to calculate the difference. Now, you're filling it with 0, so your subtracting a value from itself, which will always give 0. By leaving it empty, it uses the default value 1, so the difference with 1 row above.

Comment: Now I'm getting 0 instead of 0.0

Comment: That's very odd. Did you run it with exactly the sample data your provided in your Question? Because I get `np.nan, 10.0, 7.0, 5.0`, exactly as expected

Comment: I've added some code to my question now, does it run correctly for you?